# Prevent horizontal scrolling-Intel xdk hybrid app

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, intel-xdk

I have an app using bootstrap 3.The problem is that I can't prevent horizontal scrolling.
I tried this but it won't work:

```
html, body {
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Seems I've read (can't remember where) that `overflow-x/y` doesn't really work on most browsers... have to use just `overflow`. But I need to find some documentation for that, so don't quote me.

Comment: In particular, some CSS gets a little hairy in a webview, which is what your code is running on when you use the XDK or PhoneGap or Cordova (they are all Cordova apps). The overflow-x might work in a Crosswalk build but may not work on a regular Android build.

Comment: @philtune thanks it worked.Please post it as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems I've read (can't remember where) that `overflow-x/y` doesn't really work on most browsers... have to use just `overflow`. (needs documentation)